# Data Bind not shown in Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the `Gridview` data was bind but the values was not display on the screen.

Code:

```
gvUserManage.DataSource = dsCandiDeat.Tables[0];
gvUserManage.PageIndex = PageIndex;
gvUserManage.DataBind();
int c= gvUserManage.Rows.Count;
```

When I get the count of rows in the grid view, it shows `2`

Comment: What is the value of PageIndex? Also check for AutoGenerateColumns property? If columns are databound then it should be false else true to generate columns automatically.

Comment: Did you check AutoGenerateColumns property?

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is false

Answer (score 0):

Please check `AutoGenerateColumns` property of gridview control.

If columns are databoud then it should be `false`
else it should be true to auto generate columns